# Does Batman drop Jack Napier on purpose?

Tags: dc, batman, the-joker, batman-1989

In *Batman*, the Caped Crusader grabs hold of Jack Napier (later, the Joker), seconds before dropping him into a vat of acid.

**Was this drop intentional or not?**

Comment: Are you referring to the 1989 movie?

Comment: Why, yes, most certainly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The film's final draft script indicates that Batman **didn't** drop Jack intentionally. He simply didn't have a good grasp on him.

> [Batman reaches, **gets a poor grip.**  He stares, perplexed. at the
> stricken expression in Jack's eyes.]
>
> CUT TO: ON CATWALK - SAME MOMENT
>
> [Jack is sliding out of Batman's grasp.  A long BEAT -- **Jack looks up
> at him in terror and SLIPS AWAY** to plunge the TWO STORIES DOWN into
> the CATCH BASIN of BUBBLING, TOXIC WASTE, SCREAMING ALL THE WAY.]
>
> <sub><sup>[Batman 5th Draft Screenplay](https://sfy.ru/?script=batman_production)</sup></sub>

This is closely mirrored by the film's official novelisation, itself based on the 4th draft script.

> *Jack lost the pipe, but the Batman held him. His grip wasn’t firm;
> **Jack could feel the bat’s cloth-covered fingers slipping away.** He
> tried to reach his own hand up to grip the other’s wrist, but there
> was no strength left. Even through his burning nostrils, he could
> smell the fumes below. There was nothing left. Was this the end of the
> joke?*
>
> ***He felt his wrist slide again, felt the bat’s grasp slip by his
> fingers.***
>
> *Jack fell.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Batman: Official Movie Novelisation](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_(1989_Movie_Novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: *Cloth*? I thought all his gear was rubber?